# What's this red "A" on my property?

Tags: enterprise-architect

[image]

This is a property in an ibd diagram using sysml1.3.

I don't know what this red letter A is in the low right corner. It's the only item that has it. I guess I have done something to get it but I don't know what and googling it has not given any answer. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It contains an attachment (Linked Document). Use Ctrl-Alt-D to view it. Use the context menu to delete (or edit) it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add that in some cases by default EA (v 14) can open document like diagrams - in full view, especially for CTRL+ALT+D shortcut (or right click on element with Linked Document and after selecting from context menu option Linked Document).

For below flows EA can open Dynamic Document tab by default, as preview next to the i.e. Element Properties, instead of Linked Document:

- Start > Explore > Properties > Linked Document  or
- Show > Portals > Window > Document > Linked Document

[Default Document tab by default instead of Linked Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQVwO.png)

On Dynamic Document you won't find option to delete Linked Document:
[Delete is not available for Dynamic Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI9qX.png)

Just switch to the Linked Document, from hamburger select delete and that's it:
[Delete is available for Linked Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9gcl.png)